# Jssor (List Slider): How to end at last slide

Tags: jquery

When the Jssor List Slider (http://www.jssor.com/demos/list-slider.html) is set to Autoplay, both the slide and list item* will loop to the first (in the same transition sequence) after it hits the last one. This is confusing to users because they may not know they are on the last slide or list item.

Does anyone know how to
1. set it to scroll (in reverse) to the first slide/item after it hits the last or
2. pause/stop the looping when the last slide/item is displayed?

Thank you in advance.

*list item: text and thumbnail on the right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

new option $Loop added.

available for both slider and thumbnail navigator.

seet [jssor slider options](http://www.jssor.com/development/reference-options.html)

you'd download latest version.

Comment: $Loop works, thanks. I noticed that the jQuery version used was jquery-1.9.1.min.js. Can jssor slider work with later versions of jQuery such as v1.11.0 or v2.1.0? I am concerned because on Chrome Console, it stated, "event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead" when I tested the files. Thanks, keep up the great work!

Comment: Please don't mind 'event.returnValue', it's for ie8 or earlier and there is no harm.